# How to make natural lighting in ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, lighting

I want lighting of added projects in my ARKit project to be similar to real-world objects. Please explain how to achieve this? Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add lighting to an SCNMaterial by choosing from one of the `lightingModel` parameters e.g:

[image]

To add one of these to an SCNMaterial all you need to do is the following:

```
material.lightingModel = .constant
```

You can also make objects appear more realistic by making use of the following variable of an SCNView:

```
var autoenablesDefaultLighting: Bool { get set }
```

`autoEnablesDefaultLighting` is simply a `Boolean` value that determines whether SceneKit automatically adds lights to a scene or not.

By default this is set as false meaning that:

> the only light sources SceneKit uses for rendering a scene are those
>   contained in the scene graph.

If on the other hand, this is set to true:

> SceneKit automatically adds and places an omnidirectional light source
>   when rendering scenes that contain no lights or only contain ambient
>   lights.

To apply this setting to an `SCNView` therefore, all you need to do is use the following:

```
augmentedRealityScene.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
```

In addition to these suggestions, you can also create different types of lights to add to your scene e.g:

[image]

```
func createDirectionalLight(){

        let spotLight = SCNNode()
        spotLight.light = SCNLight()
        spotLight.scale = SCNVector3(1,1,1)
        spotLight.light?.intensity = 1000
        spotLight.castsShadow = true
        spotLight.position = SCNVector3Zero
        spotLight.light?.type = SCNLight.LightType.directional
        spotLight.light?.color = UIColor.white
}
```

Hope this helps...